# About a continuous function satisfying a given integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

> **Question:** Let $f(x):[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, satisfying the equation
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{2} f(x)(x-f(x)) \,dx = \frac{2}{3}.
> $$
>   Find $2f(1)$.

The solution took $f(x)=\frac {x}{2}$. Yes, I know it does not contradict the condition but how can we be sure that $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ and not any other function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $h(x):=f(x)-x/2$ is a continuous function in $[0,2]$ such that
$$\int_0^2h(x)^2\,dx=-\int_{0}^{2} f(x)(x-f(x)) dx+\int_{0}^{2}x^2/4dx=-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{[x^3/3]_0^2}{4}=0.$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: That is quite a hint.

Comment: @MarkViola It looks like a variational problem as $\delta\int f(x-f)dx =\int \delta f(x -2f)dx$ but I didn't find the way to save the 'elegancy' !!!. Why did you delete your answer ?.

Comment: Hi Felix.  I deleted my amswer because it was essentially the same as Robert's.

Answer (score 2):

By A.M-G.M inequality we have $$f(x)(x-f(x))\leq \Big({f(x)+x-f(x)\over 2}\Big)^2 = {x^2\over 4}$$
so we always have $$
\int_{0}^{2} f(x)(x-f(x)) \,dx \leq \int_{0}^{2} {x^2\over 4} \,dx=\frac{2}{3}.
$$
Since we have equality we have $f(x)=x-f(x)$ for each $x$ and we are done (remember that we have equality in A.M-G.M iff numbers are equal).